# OSError: Invalid argument with code that previously ran perfectly

Tags: python, file, cx-freeze

This is my a snippet from a larger program. An error occurs in this save function.

```
def save(self):
    """Write the current configuration object (self) to the configuration file."""
    try:
        open(self.config_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")
        with open(self.config_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            super().write(f)
    except PermissionError:
        sys.exit()
```

For me, and many other people, this function seems to be doing what it should be doing. Today however, I got an email from a user of my program, and he gave me the following error report.

[image: Error report]

Line 29 is the `with open(self.config_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:` line.

Two things strike me as odd.
First thing is, `config\\config.ini` is the *exact same* argument as in the line before, heck, the whole `open()` call is *exactly the same*.
Second, may be unrelated, but I still noticed it. In the error report, the directory structure is **my personal pc's directory structure, not the user's** I presume this has something to do with how cx_freeze works.

Could this problem be caused by that my first file open call is not closed properly? It works fine on thousands of systems, this one doesn't, possible, but unlikely.

Note: I am aware that the first open() call should be wrapped in a `if file.exists:` statement. This is just production code.

Anybody got an idea what's going on?

Comment: Windows doesn't let you have the same file open twice, so it might be the problem. Why are you opening the file twice, anyway?

Comment: @ThomasK I was opening the file twice to make sure it exists, stupid way to do it this way, now that I look at it again.

Thing is, it works on my own Windows 7 pc, and my Windows 8 laptop just fine, and nobody else has ever notified me of this problem, so it's weird that it happens to this one guy and only to him.

Comment: Bizarre. Could he have the file set as read-only or something?

Comment: @ThomasK I asked the user to remove the config.ini file, my program should automatically recreate the file. (the first `open()`).
It was programmatically created with the first `open()` call, so it would be very weird if it became read-only all of a sudden.

Comment: @Azeirah This is the proper way to check file existence:``os.path.exists(filename)``

Comment: @AnthonyKong I know, my `exists()` function is just a wrapper for that, I did however make a mistake in the OP, it shouldn't be `if file.exists:`, but `if exists():`